# Android Studio auto complete keeps previous text residue after carret

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete

Wherever your carret on a name that you want to change is

[image]

if you call for autocomplete (ctrl + space)

[image]

you will get a new full name instead of the only the part after carret(which is needed in this example)

[image]

The only possible way to choose another name in a clean way is to place carret at the end of the previous name

[image]

but when you want to change a name from the middle of the previous name

[image]

you have no choice other than accept the suggested name

[image]

and then delete the residue text from the previous name

[image]

Comparing previous text with new selected text from autocomplete suggestion box is implemented on many code editors. Is there any specific reason that Android Studio team decided to not to implement this feature? or may be this feature exist but is turned off by default for some reason and if this is the case how could we turn it on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **TAB** instead of **ENTER** to autocomplete changing the old value. It also works for methods.